# Want to space evenly inside column for flexible widget flutter

Tags: flutter, alignment

I want space evenly for the flexible widgets inside column. But not same type, I mean two widgets are text form field and one is text. Two flexible text form field take extra space in bottom and I don't know how they take spacing. Even if I know I can use `SizedBox()` to alignment. How can I know or remove that extra spacing for alignment.
I describe my issue.

[image: Here is photo that problem occur.]

[image: That I wrap with color container border to know extra space.]

This is my two text field code.

```
Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Paynow'),
                        style: kLabelTextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            size: 16,
                            weight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: kTextFormFieldsDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Max $remainingAmount',
                          fontSize: 13,
                          kFontColor: Colors.grey,
                        ).copyWith(helperText: ''),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        validator: _validate,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        onSaved: (value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is middle widget with text

```
Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Text(
                        'Paynow',
                        style: kLabelTextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            size: 16,
                            weight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Text(
                          'H',
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Wrap these three flexible widgets inside Column of Container

```
Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
                height: 500,
                child: Column(
                  children: [],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expanded instead of flexible to achieve an even size for each one.  Is there any specific reason you want to use flexible with this layout?

Comment: There is need to align and responsive other group of widget . So I used flexible.
Now that is OK. I used ```Center()``` widget for ```TextFormField()``` and that ```TextFormField``` move to the center of the container.

Comment: Try sharing a code sample in your answers.